# How to get a list of possible parameter values of a MATLAB function?

Tags: matlab

## Background

I am using MATLAB to script my COMSOL computations. COMSOL provides a bunch of MATLAB functions with [a poor documentation](http://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/COMSOL/4.3/doc/pdf/llmatlab/LiveLinkForMATLABUsersGuide.pdf), and I encounter the following problem.

They provide such a function

```
model.physics.create(<phystag>, physint, <geomtag>);
```

where `physint` is the so-called "constructor name". They, then, provide an example use of this function as follows.

```
phys = model.physics.create('myPhysTag', 'HeatTransfer', 'myGeomTag');
```

Hence, we know one of the allowed values for the `physint` parameter is `'HeatTransfer'`.

## Problem

However, what I need is NOT this `physint` value, `'HeatTransfer'`. But they didn't provide a list of the allowed values in their documentation list!

So I tried to dig the list out my self. Expecting there to be more information stored in the function, I did this.

```
>> model.physics
ans =
Type: Physics
>>
```

So is there a way to find out what the legal values of a parameter are in a MATLAB function?

Comment: The documentation you link to states on page 81: 'To get the constructor name, the best is to create a model using the desired physics interface in the GUI and save the model as a M-file' - does the GUI help you obtain the list you are looking for?

Comment: [Five recent questions of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2106753/farticle-pilter?tab=questions&sort=newest) have been answered and you haven't either accepted the answers or provided feedback as to why they don't solve your problem. Please consider doing so, to encourage future answers to your questions

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks for the reminder! Fixed.

Comment: @LuisMendo I really appreciate that you've clicked in and read it carefully. I agree that this line might be the key point to solve this question. But having no experience in scripting, I don't actually understand this line, in fact. Thanks a lot, again!

Answer (score 0):

the physint you are refering to sets the type of physics you want to use in your model. The values allowed here depend on what Comsol modules you have installed, e.g. you may use 'HeatTransfer' if you have the Heat Transfer Module installed and you want to use that kind of physics in your model.

As far as I know it does not work to use something like model.physics to get a list of possible values because this only gives you the features/attributes that an existing model object already has.

The best way to find out how to set the proper value for this is using the Comsol GUI, setting up a new model, selecting the physics you need and the save the model as an m-file (File/Save as.../Model file for MATLAB).

Hope that helps,